# Load default values into another table while creating user in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have table tbl_user and tbl_activity.

User can be of three types ie. Admin, Manager and Salesperson. There can be any number Admin. Only Admin can insert,update and  data into tbl_activity. 
 The tbl_activity have column user_id which separate activities of different Admin.

With Users and Activity is fine. But what I need is if Admin will created, I need to create some default activities in tbl_activity with user_id belong to newly created Admin so that it will be easy for them to understand what actually activities are. Admin can after delete or update this activities
What can be proper way to inserting these default activities in Yii2.

I try to find something in google but bad luck. Any link and tutorial will also greatly appreciated.
Here is my controller actionCreate.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
  $model = new User();
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), '') && $model->validate() && $model->save()
  {
    //data save success message here
  }
  else {
  //validation error message here
  }
 }
```

Model afterSave

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
     parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
     if($this->id && $insert == '1')
     {
         //Assign role using yii2 admin mdmsoft
         $role = Yii::$app->authManager->getRole($this->position_id);
         //if is role insert into auth_assignment table;
         if(!$role == NULL) 
         {
             Yii::$app->authManager->assign($role,$this->id);
             //if role is admin save default activity
             if($role->name == 'Admin')
             {
                 @TODO function default activity for
                 $this->defaultAdminActivity($model1->id);
             }
         }
      }
 }

 private function defaultAdminActivity($id)
 {
   //@TODO Is where I need to save default activities for Admin
   //suppose default activity is a,b and c. which i need to save to database with $id as user id.
 }
```

I have angular front end.And I am using mdmsoft yii-admin. Is better idea to create my default values array inside components and insert the components array with user id in database inside defaultAdminActivity()?

Thank You

Comment: Update your question and add your controller/action create code

Comment: afterSave() event will be the best solution for your case. Write afterSave() event in your user model file and inside this method check the user role if the role is admin add an activity to activity table. Please refer the link - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#afterSave()-detail

Comment: After adding afterSave() method, I hope your problem is solved. Still you facing any problem?

Comment: There is defaultAdminActivity() where I need to save default activities. What will be the better way to insert default activities and where to define default activity?

Comment: Calling defaultAdminActivity() method from afterSave() method is best way of creating the activity for newly added Admin. So your code is correct

Comment: And define my default activities strings inside components?